# Swift for Windows and creating GUI

Tags: swift, windows

I tried to find some answers but cannot really find anything useful. Is there possibility to create a GUI using Swift under Windows?
I do not expect a real interoperability between MacOS and Windows GUI but I can't even find any documentation about creating GUI under Windows.

Comment: while swift is opensource, the Cocoa family of libraries is not, the 'standard' UI used in iOS or Mac application is thus currently not able to be used.

Comment: That's what I assumed. Yet is there ANY way to create GUI with Swift under Windows?

Answer (score 2):

The best thing I could find in the past months was [Silver](http://www.elementscompiler.com/elements/silver/), a commercial Swift implementation/fork:

> With Silver, you can use Swift to write code directly against the .NET, Java, Android and Cocoa APIs. And you can also share a lot of non-UI code between platforms.

Developing Windows applications seems to be free, but the next option [costs $799](http://www.elementscompiler.com/elements/pricing.aspx) already.

So you could say Silver is a Swift fork with some extras.

- Swift updates and Silver updates aren't exactly in lock-step with one another, so you have to wait for the maintainers to update the language to be truly source compatible.
- Silver [extends the language](https://docs.elementscompiler.com/Silver/LanguageExtensions/) with stuff familiar to Java/C# people.
- See other [limitations](https://docs.elementscompiler.com/Silver/DifferencesAndLimitations/).

It seems Silver isn't even 1.0, yet.

---

I cannot add personal experience; I'm torn at the moment. It looks cool but I don't know how productive you can be, writing code in the latest Swift to compose your types and then hitting language road bumps in Silver. I guess that's why there's a Silver Cocoa bridge: because you'll be writing Silver code, not Swift code, although both are pretty similar.

Answer (score 2):

There are some GUI examples in 'Swift for Windows' project at http://SwiftForWindows.github.io but the GUI toolkit is alpha version.